# how to remove rows in an associate array based on duplicate column values php

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have this Associate array. Quick Track Club appears twice I want to remove the entire row of any duplicates that are in the Name column. using php

```
0 | Array
0 => 1
1 => Long Beach Sprinters
2 => LBS
3 => 1
4 => 0
5 => 0
6 => FALSE
7 => 0
1 | Array
0 => 2
1 => Quick Track Club
2 => QTC
3 => 1
4 => 0
5 => 0
6 => FALSE
7 => 0
2 | Array
0 => 3
1 => Mark Of a Champion
2 => MaC
3 => 2
4 => 0
5 => 0
6 => FALSE
7 => 0
3 | Array
0 => 4
1 => Unattached
2 => Unattached
3 => 2
4 => 0
5 => 0
6 => FALSE
7 => 0
4 | Array
0 => 5
1 => Quick Track Club
2 => QTC
3 => 2
4 => 0
5 => 0
6 => FALSE
7 => 0
```

it should look lice this without the second occurrence of Quick Track Club.
array_unique doesn't work because the entire row is not identical I am creating the array from a csc file

```
0 | Array
0 => 1
1 => Long Beach Sprinters
2 => LBS
3 => 1
4 => 0
5 => 0
6 => FALSE
7 => 0
1 | Array
0 => 2
1 => Quick Track Club
2 => QTC
3 => 1
4 => 0
5 => 0
6 => FALSE
7 => 0
2 | Array
0 => 3
1 => Mark Of a Champion
2 => MaC
3 => 2
4 => 0
5 => 0
6 => FALSE
7 => 0
3 | Array
0 => 4
1 => Unattached
2 => Unattached
3 => 2
4 => 0
5 => 0
6 => FALSE
7 => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to keep a tally of used names and filter for it.

```
$names = [];
$associates = array_filter($associates, function($a) { return (!in_array($a[1], $names) && $names[]=$a[1];)});
```

Comment: The fields will constantly change multiple times on a daily basis. This is for an app that I created. So I will never know what the names are.

Comment: I don’t see how this solution doesn’t work. It doesn’t rely on hard coded names